# How to access href of an a tag having ul with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the value of the href of mi `<a>` tag which is within  a ul that has a id

```
<ul id="nav-social">
    <li>
        <a class="waves-effect" href="link" target="_blank">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="waves-effect" href="link" target="_blank">
    </li>
</ul>
```

i only need the first link and then the second in another method

i tried this

```
var href = $('a:first').attr('href');
var url = $('#nav-social').html(href);
```

but is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#nav-social li a:first").attr("href")`

`$("#nav-social li a:last").attr("href") // if there are only 2 links`

Alternatively, you can use index based selection using `eq(index)`

`$("#nav-social li a").eq(0).attr("href"); // first link`

`$("#nav-social li a").eq(1).attr("href"); // second link`

Comment: nice thanks! when i need the second link?, i suppose theres no a second function :P

Comment: I updated my answer.. it should take care of everything

Comment: it higlights as unneficient jquery usage on phpstorm any clue why?

Comment: is says this  It suggests to split descendant selectors which are prefaced with ID selector and warns about duplicated selectors which could be cached

Comment: I think it wants you to do something like `$("#nav-social").find("li a")` instead of `$("#nav-social li a")` for performance benefits.. which I think in latest jquery versions, the benefit is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eq()` method.

```
var url1 = $("#nav-social li a").eq(0).attr("href")    //first
var url2 = $("#nav-social li a").eq(1).attr("href")    //second
```